# How to copy array into file in phonegap?

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have array of images as follows:

```
var imageArray = new Array(10);

function onCameraPicSuccess (imgData)  {
  imageArray.push("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgData);
}
```

I am copying captured images into this array.

Now how to copy this array into file? I am using phonegap.
I want to copy into particular folder like myPhotos in my local place.
Any help?

Is it possible to do it in javascript?
Or should i call JAVA applet from javascript to write into file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [FileWriter API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) to write a string version of your data to the disk.

**Quick Example**

```
function win(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
        console.log("write success");
    };
    writer.write(JSON.stringify(imageArray));
};

var fail = function(evt) {
    console.log(error.code);
};

entry.createWriter(win, fail);
```

For the whole context, see the Full Example under the FileWriter API [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter).

You can use the [FileReader API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) to read data back. Remember to call [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn it back to a JavaScript object.

Comment: ok but i want to save to some separate file,not to the disk.Like myLocalPlace/myPhotos

Comment: Where this file will be saved?Can somebody tell me?Its not mentioned in documentation

Comment: As long as you can read/write to it, why does it matter where it's stored? Android stores the file in /data/data/com.[app-name]/[file] if I remember correctly. There are methods to [move or copy the file to different locations](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry) search for "moveTo".

Comment: I cant save images in file writer api.. Only text data can save like this . If i save images it cannot be open

Comment: base64 encode them first, that turns image data into text format.